# How to check if list of polygons intersects with each other?

Tags: postgis, postgresql

I have a rectangle polygon which divides my country into small grids (like tiling). I have a system in which by selecting single/multiple features users can send applications to get license to those single/multiple selected polygons. But there is one requirement. All selected features must be in neighborhood (must intersect with wall, edge intersection is not considered).
For example, if user selected these like this

[image]

the system should say **ok (true)**, because all polygons have **connections**.

If user selections like this:

[image]

then, it checking algorithm should say that it is **not ok (false)**, because the upper-left polygon does not intersect with its walls, which means edge intersection is not counted. Same conclusion applies to the last image, I should get False.

[image]

Are there any ready functions/algorithms to check such conditions? I am looking for PostGIS solutions/recommendations.
Users will select polygons from the drop-down list and press the **check** button to see the results.

Comment: One question per Question, please. Choose PostGIS or Python, and make an attempt, though dissolving and counting parts would suffice either way.

Comment: @Vince, thanks for your comment. okay i will change

Comment: SQL questions should contain SQL code.

Comment: Is the selection an UI frontend application? If so, save yourself a roundtrip to the server and DB (and *comparably* more costly spatial relationship operations) and simply lookup **tile indices `(col, row)`** as keys in a map (with altering `(col+-1, row+-1)`) of previously selected.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If the rectangles are all edge-adjacent, then their union will be a single polygon. If not, it will be a MultiPolygon with more than one element. So,
union the rectangles, and then test if `ST_NumGeometries(union)` equals 1.

```
ST_NumGeometries( ST_Union( geom )) = 1 AS isEdgeAdjacent
```